Network graph issue in highchart 9
This code is working fine with highchart version 7 but after upgrading highchart vesrion 9 it is causing issue. All co-ordinates of all nodes and paths are getting set to 0. And graph is appearing as single marker in extreme left corner of  div. Also console logs are clear. But still graph is not visible
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsNetworkgraph from 'highcharts/modules/networkgraph';

// Initialize the network graph module
HighchartsNetworkgraph(Highcharts);

// Sample data for the network graph
const data = [
    ['A', 'B'],
    ['A', 'C'],
    ['B', 'D'],
    ['C', 'D'],
    ['D', 'E'],
    ['E', 'F'],
    ['F', 'A']
];

// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'networkgraph',
        layoutAlgorithm: {
            enableSimulation: true
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Basic Network Graph'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        networkgraph: {
            keys: ['from', 'to'],
            layoutAlgorithm: {
                enableSimulation: true
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            linkFormat: ''
        },
        data: data
    }]
});


Hi @Jay, Which exact Highcharts version are you using? Your code seems to work with Highcharts v9: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/woj4tkmr/

Yes it is working on jsfiddle but in my project it not rendering correctly. No additional css is applied but still all co-ordinates are set to zero

Yes it is working on jsfiddle but in my project it not rendering correctly. No additional css is applied but still all co-ordinates are set to zero

We need to reproduce the issue to check what is wrong. Please try to use jsfiddle or create a small project on GitHub with the reproduction.

Yes that is the issue not able to recreate in any other place

I'm sorry, but without reproducing the problem no one will be able to help you. You can try to separate only the chart component. Maybe you are using something specific in your project that could affect the chart?
